# Conditional delete in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete any rows including specific string in dataframe.

I want to delete data rows with abnormal email address (with `.jpg`)

Here's my code, what's wrong with it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'email':['abc@gmail.com', 'cde@gmail.com', 'ghe@ss.jpg', 'sldkslk@sss.com']})

df

             email
0    abc@gmail.com
1    cde@gmail.com
2       ghe@ss.jpg
3  sldkslk@sss.com

for i, r in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[i,'email'][-3:] == 'com':
        df.drop(df.index[i], inplace=True) 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-84-4f12d22e5e4c>", line 2, in <module>
    if df.loc[i,'email'][-3:] == 'com':

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1472, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 870, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 998, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1911, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_key(key, axis)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1798, in _validate_key
    error()

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1785, in error
    axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))

KeyError: 'the label [2] is not in the [index]'
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do this rather than iterating through your frame with `iterrows`:

```
df = df[df.email.str.endswith('.com')]
```

which returns:

```
>>> df
             email
0    abc@gmail.com
1    cde@gmail.com
3  sldkslk@sss.com
```

Or, for larger dataframes, it's sometimes faster to not use the `str` methods provided by `pandas`, but just to do it in a plain list comprehension with python's built in string methods:

```
df = df[[i.endswith('.com') for i in df.email]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this method. Anyway, what's the problem with my code?

Comment: Besides the fact that `iterrows` is kind of slow and clunky, not much. It would work if your replaced `==` with `!=` and `df.drop(df.index[i], inplace=True)` with `df.drop(i, inplace=True)`